# Expected a class member. :19

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';



class login_screen extends StatelessWidget {
  const login_screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomSheet: const Text(
        'Hello',
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(),
        title: const Text(
        'Hello',
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children:
          [
            Row(
              children:
              [
                Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children:
                  const [
                   Text(
                     'Hello AbdelAzim',
                     style: TextStyle(
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                       fontSize: 30,
                     ),
                   ),

                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the full error message, as well as more details in the body of your question as to the problem that you are experiencing

Answer (score 2):

Just Change your appBar like below hope its help to you,and run your app

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: const Text(
    'Hello',
     ),
 ),
```